# connect a arduino to a ANDROID phone through USB via com port

Tags: android, serial-port, arduino

in my project i need to connect a arduino to a ANDROID tablet.. i think it easy to connect through the com port using USB ports on both of the devises. and to communicate each other using serial communication...

i have connected my arduino to the lap top and send and retrieve data from it in c# platform. but i don't know either is it possible or how do do it in ANDROID platform...

is there are any tutorial or any examples for this problem witch is have faced?

```
[MonitoringDescriptionAttribute("SerialPortDesc")]
public class SerialPort : Component
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple tutorials on the web teaching how to do that.
I'll list a few, maybe it can get you some help.

- http://www.instructables.com/id/How-control-arduino-board-using-an-android-phone-a/
- http://www.hobbyist.co.nz/?q=android-control-arduino

Library:

- https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Android Open Accessory Protocol 2.0](https://source.android.com/accessories/aoa2.html).